# Can someone explain why there's a one-year difference in the results of PHP's date diff function for these two dates with the same timezone?

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone, datediff

```php
$a = new DateTime("2023-05-31", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));
$b = new DateTime("1970-05-31", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));
var_dump($a->diff($b)->y);
// int(52)

$a = new DateTime("2023-05-30", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));
$b = new DateTime("1970-05-30", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));
var_dump($a->diff($b)->y);
// int(53)
```

Why in the first case the diff is 52?

I expect 53 for both cases

Comment: The interval for the first is `interval: - 52y 11m 30d 23:00:00.0,` -- Not sure why it's an hour off

Comment: Seems to be a quirk with Rome. Doesn't happen with London or Paris

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be something about Italy in general. Possibly they didnt do a Summer time one year that is confusing the function (Thats a guess)

```
$zones = [
        'Europe/Rome', 'Europe/Malta', 'Europe/San_Marino', 'Europe/Vatican',
        
        'Europe/Amsterdam', 'Europe/Andorra', 'Europe/Astrakhan',   'Europe/Athens', 
        'Europe/Belgrade', 'Europe/Berlin', 'Europe/Bratislava', 'Europe/Brussels',
        'Europe/Bucharest' ,'Europe/Budapest', 'Europe/Busingen', 'Europe/Chisinau',
        'Europe/Copenhagen', 'Europe/Dublin', 'Europe/Gibraltar', 'Europe/Guernsey',
        'Europe/Helsinki',  'Europe/Isle_of_Man', 'Europe/Istanbul', 'Europe/Jersey',
        'Europe/Kaliningrad', 'Europe/Kirov' ,  'Europe/Kyiv',  'Europe/Lisbon',
        'Europe/Ljubljana', 'Europe/London', 'Europe/Luxembourg', 'Europe/Madrid',
         'Europe/Mariehamn', 'Europe/Minsk', 'Europe/Monaco',
        'Europe/Moscow', 'Europe/Oslo', 'Europe/Paris', 'Europe/Podgorica',
        'Europe/Prague','Europe/Riga' , 'Europe/Samara',
         'Europe/Sarajevo' ,    'Europe/Saratov', 'Europe/Simferopol',
        'Europe/Skopje', 'Europe/Sofia' ,   'Europe/Stockholm', 'Europe/Tallinn',
        'Europe/Tirane', 'Europe/Ulyanovsk',    'Europe/Vaduz', 
        'Europe/Vienna', 'Europe/Vilnius',  'Europe/Volgograd', 'Europe/Warsaw',
        'Europe/Zagreb', 'Europe/Zurich'];

foreach ( $zones as $zone){
    $tz = new DateTimeZone($zone);
    $a = new DateTime("2023-05-31", $tz);
    $b = new DateTime("1970-05-31", $tz);
    if ( $a->diff($b)->y != 53) {
        printf (" !!! %s diff = %d\n", $zone, $a->diff($b)->y);
    } else {
        #printf ("%s diff = %d\n", $zone, $a->diff($b)->y);
    }
    
}
```

RESULTS

```
 !!! Europe/Rome diff = 52
 !!! Europe/Malta diff = 52
 !!! Europe/San_Marino diff = 52
 !!! Europe/Vatican diff = 52
```

> It also does not happen if you start from 1971, so maybe the year with an issue is 1970

**Found this** on `https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/italy/rome?year=1970` which may go some way to explain.

```
31 May 1970 - Daylight Saving Time Started
When local standard time was about to reach
Sunday, 31 May 1970, 00:00:00 clocks were turned forward 1 hour to

Sunday, 31 May 1970, 01:00:00 local daylight time instead.

Sunrise and sunset were about 1 hour later on 31 May 1970 than the day before. 
There was more light in the evening.

Also called Spring Forward, Summer Time, and Daylight Savings Time.
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested it myself, and I noticed something interesting. As I mentioned in my comment, there was a 1 hour difference between the 31st dates, but then I noticed this:

```
$b = new DateTime("1970-05-31", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));
// = DateTime @12956400 {#7126
// date: 1970-05-31 01:00:00.0 Europe/Rome (+02:00),
// }

$b = new DateTime("1970-05-30", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));
 // = DateTime @12870000 {#7124
// date: 1970-05-30 00:00:00.0 Europe/Rome (+01:00),
// }
```

As you can see, on the 31st, there's a 2 hour offset, but on the 30th, there's a 1 hour offset. Checking with https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/italy/rome , the time changed on May 31st, 1970 at 12:00 am, so the 12am hour didn't actually exist, and it jumped to 1am. The comparison does a full comparison, and so the difference is actually `52y 11m 30d 23:00:00.0`